# VSCode Run Selection in Terminal and Advance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a a shortcut for the Python extension in VSCode that allows to execute selected lines of code in Terminal and advance the cursor to the next line? I can only find `python.execSelectionInTerminal`, which runs code selection in terminal but does not advance the cursor to the next line.

I did find the shortcut `python.datascience.runcurrentcelladvance`, but it does not work when executing Python code in Terminal.

If no shortcut exists currently, how can I create one?

Comment: See http://actuarialdatascience.com/shortcut_vscode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in shortcut. You can make a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Answer (score -1):

You can run jupyter notebook on VS Code, if you've installed it. Just open any .ipynb file and wait for the server to start automatically (can take upto a minute). If you haven't installed, it's just a simple

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

on powershell.

Comment: I have Jupyter Notebooks installed, but don't want to use it. I want to use the Terminal.